# What microphones setup is suitable to record both a moving speaker and questions from the audience?

Tags: microphone, hardware

I am trying to improve the sound quality for following situation:
- the speaker stand in front of a 20-30 people crowd.
- the speaker moves around in front of the audience
- the speaker writes from time to time on a board
- an audience member asks a question from time to time

what are some hardware equipment one could use to have a good quality audio recording? Budget is about 300 Euros

BR
Stefan

Comment: you mention "recording". Do you want to amplify the sound in the room as well, or do you just want to record?

Comment: Just record the sound.

Answer (score 1):

You need a lavalier microphone with a wireless transmitter for the presenter and a roving hand-held wireless microphone for the audience questions.

You then need a device to receive the wireless transmissions and a field recorder to record the audio with some headphones to monitor.

There is pretty much no chance you will get this for 300 Euros.

Comment: Apparently, you can get wireless sets that fit his budget (https://www.smartphonefilmpro.com/what-are-the-best-budget-wireless-microphones-for-smartphones/),